# Realm concurrent write of data

Tags: android, realm

When I write to db from 2 diferent threads is used queue for processing of data? This manner is used.

```
realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
  r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmUser);
});
```

Comment: Transactions block each other and are executed sequentially.